# Database backup from Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 system. I am trying to take back up of database but it does not work,

```
user1@rajeshN ~ $ sudo pg_dump -U postgres teleshop_development1 > pg_backup
[sudo] password for user1: 
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "teleshop_development1" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

So I switched to postgres, And tried there but I do not know password

```
user1@rajeshN ~ $ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@rajeshN:~$ 
postgres@rajeshN:~$ sudo pg_dump -U postgres teleshop_development1 > pg_backup
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
```

Please suggest how can I get password or back up.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reset the password. If you can't access the pg server to reset it (because it requires a password), change the *auth-method* value to *trust* in pg_hba.conf to allow you to access without a password, then go reset it, and change *auth-method* back to its original value.

Comment: @eurotrash I read documentation of pg_hba.conf about adding IP in it. I will check. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are already the user "postgres", do not use `sudo` again. Its just

```
postgres@rajeshN:~$ pg_dump teleshop_development1 > pg_backup
```

**Or** you can do it all in one line

```
user1@rajeshN ~ $ sudo -u postgres pg_dump teleshop_development1 > pg_backup
```

Comment: How can I reset password of user `postgres@Ascra:~$`

Answer (score 1):

Specify PostgreSQL password, EG with `-W`.

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, I used @C14L answer